# Allocating memory for stock-like adding integers

Tags: c++, c

I have two knows arrays - each array's element contains a digit, all of them become a number. I have to add these two numbers and create outcome array in the same design.

Now, how do I add these numbers? Well, just like in a stack, I take first elements from these two arrays, add them, and save into the, let's say - outcome[0].

Then I take the next first elements of these two arrays (I deleted the previous ones - took it out from the stack), add them, and put into the top of the outcome array.

If an overflow happend (x > 9), I erase the last digit, and put it on the top.

This way I should get the proper results.

---

After I explained you my cool project, it's time to get to the actual question - how could I allocate the memory for the outcome array?

I mean, I don't really know how many overflows there will be (== how many times will I have to enlarge outcomes array), I don't know if the result of adding two XX numbers will result in XXX or XX number, etc...

I've been thinking about this for a long time and can't come up with anything. Well, maybe except for allocating something like sizeof(int)*999 to make 100% sure :D...

Comment: This is a poor question. The details of the algorithm are not interesting if all you're after is understanding memory management in C, so you should rewrite the question to contain only one meaningful topic. And if you already know memory management, then don't mention it in the question.

Comment: I could write: "how much memory to allocate if I wanna consider unknown number of overflows, and digits in the result", but without the intro nobody would understand what I mean.

Comment: On the other hand, "how to resize an array dynamically" would be quite clear and sufficient...

Comment: Also, it's generally advisable to pick a single language (either C++ or C) otherwise people won't know what answer you want. If you don't mind solutions being in either language, specify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged this [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I would suggest [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and [`std::stack`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/).

The number of overflows will be at most the number of digits you have in your arrays. So, for [c](/questions/tagged/c), I would say allocate the maximum of the size of array1 and array2 plus 1.

Comment: I added c++ just out of curiosity of an alternative answer, thanks. However, I'm much more interested in C solution.

Comment: Glad @user wasn't curious about Perl, too. That could get really confusing.

Comment: @user2252786 `malloc()` and `realloc()`.